# SQL Server Error Invalid column name 'NaN'

Tags: c#, sql-server, nan

I'm having a bit of an issue. I am getting some values from my program's SQL Server database, doing some calculations with them, and then writing the calculated values back to the database. However, some values are giving me `"Error Invalid column name 'NaN'."` There really isn't anything unique about the columns that are causing this issue. They are the same float type columns as the columns that are working perfectly.

```
con.Open();

AddPhase1Calc = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Asset SET Make_Up_Depr = " + Make_Up_Depr + " WHERE Asset_ID = " + a, con);

AddPhase1Calc.ExecuteNonQuery();


con.Close();
```

I'm not sure if this is enough code but this is the first column that is causing me the issue.

Comment: warning. your code is susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Daniel: it depends on where Make_Up_Depr comes from.  If it's not from user input, then it's much less likely.

Comment: true, but still its hard to tell.

Comment: Make_Up_Depr is the result of an equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess Make_Up_Depr is a double and that the calculation is evaluating zero divided by zero in some cases.  Which results in the value being NaN, and SQL is trying to evaluate it to a column name/alias (since it's not a double value...)

Comment: I've never seen a language where division by zero results in NaN.

Comment: Sorry, ZERO divided by zero.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx

Comment: Thank you sir i fixed the columns that were dividing by zero and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put single quotes around the `Make_Up_Depr` value:

```
AddPhase1Calc = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Asset SET Make_Up_Depr = '" + Make_Up_Depr +
    "' WHERE Asset_ID = " + a, con);
```

Also, you should never build a SQL statement that way. You're open to SQL injection attacks if the variable comes from user input. You should be using parameters instead.

Finally, this code needs to be in a `using` block:

```
using (SqlConnection con = whatever)
{
    con.Open();

    using (AddPhase1Calc = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Asset SET Make_Up_Depr = '" + 
      Make_Up_Depr + "' WHERE Asset_ID = " + a, con))
    {
        AddPhase1Calc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your values, either `Make_Up_Depr` or `a` is evaluating to `NaN`.  Since this is a string, SQL Server thinks you are trying to reference a column by that name.